# JMeter Xpath2 extractor id's matching multiple conditions

Tags: jmeter, xpath-2.0

Below is the sample XML fragment, from it i'm trying to filter out id's of articles matching both conditions as below. Currently i could extract id's for individual condition with help of expression below

1. get Avaialable articles, Xpath2 expression = `(//*//*//*//*[starts-with(state,'Avaialable')])/id`
2. get articles name starting with 'A' () , Xpath2 expression = `(//*//*//*//*[starts-with(name,'A')])/id`

I want to merge these conditions in a single expression and would like to

> fetch id's of Articles where Name starts with 'A'  **AND**  articles which
> are Available

. Tried multiple ways but not working as expected.

Dummy XML fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:GetArtclesResponse
    xmlns:ns2="XXX"
    xmlns:ns4="XXX"
    xmlns:ns3="XXX"
    xmlns:ns6="XXX"
    xmlns:ns5="XXX"
    xmlns:ns8="XXX"
    xmlns:ns7="XXX"
    xmlns:ns13="XXX"
    xmlns:ns9="XXX"
    xmlns:ns12="XXX"
    xmlns:ns11="XXX">
    <serverTimeInfo timezone="+00:00" timestamp="1606409365419"/>
    <items>
        <count>2</count>
        <articles>
           <article>
                <name>ABC</name>
                <id>1234</id>
                <state>Avaialable</state>
            </article>
            <article>
                <name>XYZ</name>
                <id>3456</id>
                <state>Avaialable_Conditional</state>
            </article>
        </articles>
    </items>
</ns3:GetArtclesResponse>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `and` to check both:

```
(//*//*//*//*[starts-with(state,'Avaialable') and starts-with(name,'A')])/id
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to **combine** 2 different XPath expressions you can use [`|` (union) operator](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/xpath/xpath-union-operator-example/) like:

   ```
    //article[state = 'Avaialable']  |  //article[starts-with(name,'A')]
   ```

   it will return you both:

   - nodes which have state=Available
   - and nodes which name starts with A
2. If you want to combine 2 conditions in a single XPath expression - go for `and` operator like:

   ```
   //article[state = 'Avaialable' and starts-with(name,'A')]
   ```

   it will return

   - nodes which nave state=available and whose name attribute starts with a

More information:

- [XPath Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp)
- [The JMeter XPath2 Extractor: How to Achieve Better Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations)